# Store Facebook user data in database

Tags: php, facebook

I'm trying to store this in the database but it's not working. Is there a better way to do this? It's picking up the user session but it won't insert the data into the database.

```
if($user)
{   
    $user_interest = $facebook->api('/me/interests');   

    for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($user_interest[data]); $i++) 
    {
        $name = $user_interest[data][$i]['name'];
        $category = $user_interest[data][$i]['category'];
        $categoryId = $user_interest[data][$i]['id'];
        $created_time = $user_interest[data][$i]['created_time'];

        $strsql = "INSERT INTO `interests`(`fbId`,`categoryId`,`category`,`name`,`created_time`) 
                   VALUES(\"$fbId\",\"$categoryId\",\"$category\",\"$name\",\"$created_time\")";
        mysql_query($strsql, $connect) or die(mysql_error());
        $chkrow1 = mysql_affected_rows($connect);
    }
```

Comment: ٍWhat happens after that? What is the error message?

Comment: what is error? Please post error

Comment: no error message, page loads just fine

Answer (score 2):

```
"INSERT INTO `interests`(`fbId`,`categoryId`,`category`,`name`,`created_time`)
 VALUES(\"$fbId\",\"$categoryId\",\"$category\",\"$name\",\"$created_time\")";
```

Strings in MySQL (and other SQL) use single quotes.

```
"INSERT INTO `interests`(`fbId`,`categoryId`,`category`,`name`,`created_time`)
 VALUES('$fbId', '$categoryId', '$category', '$name', '$created_time')";
```

Also, escape all of those values using `mysql_real_escape_string` before interpolating them, then stop using the deprecated `mysql_` extensions and use parametrized queries with PDO.